# WICKET: how to get client's ip/address

Tags: java, ip, wicket

I'm using wicket 1.5.1, couldn't figure this out.

```
public class MyPage extends WebPage {

public MyPage() {

    String clientAddress = ...?
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
    WebRequest req = (WebRequest) RequestCycle.get().getRequest();
    HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) req.getContainerRequest();
    String clientAddress = httpReq.getRemoteHost();
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `httpReq.getRemoteAddr()`?

Comment: `getRemoteAddr()` will return the raw IP address, while `getRemoteHost()` will return the resolved address name if possible (or the IP if not).

Answer (score 3):

Subclass `WebClientInfo` to provide a public method that delegates on protected [`WebClientInfo.getRemoteAddr()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.3.4/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/request/WebClientInfo.java#WebClientInfo.getRemoteAddr%28org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebRequestCycle%29). Then create a method to query this in a custom `RequestCycle` class. In Wicket 1.3-1.4 I've achieved this by subclassing `RequestCycle`, but with 1.5 it seems things are different: [RequestCycle in Wicket 1.5](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/requestcycle-in-wicket-15.html)

`WebClientInfo` has the advantage of querying the [`X-Forwarded-For`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) erquest parameter, and will return the proper IP address if your server is behind a proxy/load balancer that uses [XFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For).

Comment: How do I get an instance of WebClientInfo in Wicket 6?

Comment: @Artem Look at the code in org.apache.wicket.markup.html.pages.BrowserInfoPage for detailed informations

Answer (score 2):

Using Wicket 6 and 7, you can do the following:

```
String remoteAddress = ((WebClientInfo)Session.get().getClientInfo())
                      .getProperties()
                      .getRemoteAddress();
```